# How to display search results with ajax in django project?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, frontend

I am working in a Django project where one of the functionalities will be that user could search a name (using a form), the view will search that name in database (after some transformation), and the results will be displayed below the form.

At the moment, It is necesary that the entire page loads every time a search is submitted. I am working in apply ajax to make this dynamic. The problem is that when I return the search result as a JsonResponse, I am not able to see the data in the success function of ajax.

**Views.py**

```
def indexView (request):
    form = FriendForm ()
    friends = Friend.objects.all ()
    return render (request, "index.html", {"form": form, "friends": friends})


def searchFriend(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        form = FriendForm (request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            if request.is_ajax():
                name = form.cleaned_data['name']
                query = Friend.objects.filer(first_name__contains=name)

                print(query)
                return JsonResponse(list(query), safe=False)

            else:
                return JsonResponse(form.errors)
```

**Main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
    var search = $("#searchField").val();
    

        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "search/ajax/friend/",
            success: function(data) { // on success..
                console.log(data)
              
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your query getting printed in terminal ?
`Friend.objects.filer` use `filter` instead of `filer`
and use `type: 'post'` instead of  `method: 'post',`
and add  `data: $(search).serialize(),` instead of `data: $(this).serialize(),`

Comment: thanks,  I used serializers.serialize() before returning my json and it worked. The problem now is that I realized that my form is not really posting any data and  ""name = form.cleaned_data['name']""  is always empty.....